# Incomplete output on os/exec when executing psql commands

Tags: go, exec, psql

I'm currently using `os/exec` to run many `psql` commands in sequence.

My problem is that if there's an error during the execution of the script, the output doesn't show it.

Example: 
When executing the command file from the command line, the output is this:

```
SET
CREATE FUNCTION
psql:update-14.3.7.1/dml/----------------xxxxxxxx.sql:33: ERROR:  null value in column "tipoxxxxxxxx" violates not-null constraint
DETALHE:  Failing row contains (9, 0, null, null, null, null, AAAAAAAAA_BBBBBBBBBB_CCCCC_BANANA, null, null, null).
CONTEXTO:  SQL statement "insert INTO ----------------xxxxxxxx
        (id,versao,tipoxxxxxxxx,carrotdeapplefinal,carrotdetttttttt,ativa,funcionalidade,driver,alterar_na_xxxxxxxx)
        values
        (nextval('sq_----------------xxxxxxxx'),0,tipoaaaaaaaaa,carrotapple,carrottttttttt,alterarNaxxxxxxxx)"
PL/pgSQL function createorupdateaaaaaaaaa() line 22 at SQL statement
DROP FUNCTION
```

And executing the exact same file from the Go code, the output is:

```
SET
CREATE FUNCTION
DROP FUNCTION
```

My Go code for running commands(and showing the output) is:

```
    cmd := exec.Command(comando, argList...)
    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    cmdS := out.String()
    fmt.Println("cmdS", cmdS)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("XYZ")
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
    }
```

How to modify my code to show the other lines of the output?

Comment: Are you sure the rest of the output isn't on Stderr?

Comment: @JimB That was the problem, modified it and it worked. Can you make a answer clarifying that even if `err` is `nil`, `stderr` might not be empty? Just so I can thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs can use `stderr` and `stdout` however they choose. The presence of an execution error has no bearing on whether there was something written to `stderr` or not.

Always check both streams when looking for all output from a program.